# Export not Working

Tags: export, unity, .fbx, obj

I am planning on using this model in a Unity game. When I try to export the simple drawer I made, both .fbx and .obj aren't exporting properly. Both the textures and details in the drawers are not exporting properly. Is there a setting I have to enable or am I doing something wrong?

[Download of .blend and .blend1](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/9r64a1j4wozqx6n/AACHa1uBA0EsAKCsQ_P5_TQqa?dl=1)

[image: What rendering in Cycles looks like]

[image: What exporting in .fbx does]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you place your .fbx file and the "texture" folder in the same level of the explorer (windows). Also, you need to make sure that path is targeted on your image node in the texture. Lastly use PRINCIPLED shader only. Any other networks nodes (ramp, musgrave, etc..) will not go into export.
Also: Select your object, then
File>Export>.FBX (the file explorer opens), press N to get the options of exporting and make sure you have marked "geometry" and "export selected".
[image]